# Programming grunt-rev/grunt-usemin to use commit-id

Tags: gruntjs

The default behavior of grunt-rev is to evaluate the given resource and put a hash of the content in the path, so /images/sprites/rewards.png becomes /images/sprites/f936712a.rewards.png

I don't want that.  I've got several revisions being served simultaneously and I want to be able to delete old revs at will, so I'd like to rename it to  /2013-06-10-e75607/images/sprites/rewards.png (where e75607 is the commit-id for the whole revision, nothing to do with the individual file).

Is this a possibility with grunt-rev and grunt-usemin?  Is there an equivalent tool that would do it?

**Edit**

Several people have asked me why not use the hash of each file.  Let me explain:

In old-fashion websites, in response to pretty much any user input, the browser is reloaded, the back-end generates a brand new page from the input, the HTML is sent to to the browser, which displays the page.  It's a slow, CPU- and bandwidth-intensive process, but it does have one advantage: all the assets that are ever loaded are loaded together, within a few seconds.

In a more modern website, the page that is loaded describes the whole application.  When the user makes some input, the Javascript on the page renders new DOM elements and loads new assets as needed.   The page as a whole is rarely or never reloaded The site is enormously more responsive in consequence (and much easier to develop, more secure, cheaper to run, and on and on) but has the corresponding disadvantage: an asset might be loaded hours or days after the page is loaded.

Say, you visit the site at 10 am, when the site is running version cd1d0906.  At 10:30, the site is upgraded to version 4b571377.  At 11 am, you press a button that causes a popup that is rendered with a image called sprite.png.  Obviously, you need the cd1d0906 version of sprite.png -- not the 4b571377 version.

Therefore, a well-maintained site will continue to offer old versions of all assets for several days after the versions have changed over.  The easiest way to do that is to keep all the assets in a directory that is named after the version.

The complaint that this "unnecessarily" discards cache entries for unchanged files is rather unconvincing.  Most deployed assets are CSS files, JS files, and sprites, all of which are compilation of many smaller files.  It's a rare deployment that doesn't changes *one* CSS file and *one* JS file and *one* sprited image.  The cache is rarely valuable after a version change.

Comment: Why? The generated hash will be different if the assets changes between revisions, so I don't really see the use-case.

Comment: Wow.  The number of times I get this objection is beginning to make me dizzy.  I'll put an explanation in the original question.

Comment: valid points those of yours @Malvolio